# I have added new field to SSRS VS2017 report, but the data is not showing in the preview

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have been trying to add a field to an existing SSRS report.
Added the field in the dataset through the Query, the query brings data. Then I have added to the report, where it's not showing the data.
I have deleted the rdl.data file not helping
I have refreshed the fields from dataset report --not helping
I have deleted the dataset and re-created new one -- this is also not helping
I have tried the project properties to toggle to dataset option, that's also not helping
Nothing is helping, and any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: So just to be clear, this isn't working (not showing the data) on the report when you run it from the designer?

Comment: Whats type of data is in the fields you are adding and how long is it? I've seen instances where it's long text data with hidden CR/LF which is forcing the data onto a new line and therefore does not appear to be showing in the report. Try expanding the textbox and also exporting to excel and checking the contents there by clicking in the cell in Excel and expanding the formula bar

Comment: it was not showing the data, then I rebooted my desktop. It's all pickedup now and the data is showing now.

Comment: This sounds like a .Data file issue where you just needed to delete the .Data file with the old data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210078/why-is-my-ssrs-report-showing-old-data